# Libgdx - Cannot cast MapLayer to TiledMapTileLayer

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled

I am trying to use Tiled with my Libgdx game. I am having trouble with this line of code:

```
TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) tiledMap.getLayers().get(0);
```

I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapLayer cannot be cast to com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer

I am using Libgdx 0.9.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the layer a tile layer or an object layer? Only tile layers will be instances of `TiledMapTileLayer`.

Comment: It was an object layer. Thank you.